# How to create a ListView dynamically , just below the clicked view?

Tags: android

I want to develop a list view dynamically ,just below the clicked view.
I had create 3 TextView Dynamically. now after applying click on any text view a list view need to be appear just below the selected text view. Now problem is that, I am getting my dynamically created textview successfully , but not able to get listview at required position. If any one is able to help , then please help me.

my codes are below:-

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    String []menu={"One","Two","three"};
    String [] submenu={"One","Two","Three"};
    TextView tv1;
    ListView list1;
LinearLayout latout;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,submenu);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(20,10,10,0);
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {



            tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv1.setText(menu[i]);
            tv1.setTag(i);
            tv1.setId(i);
            tv1.setTextSize(20);

            tv1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_material_dark));
            //tv1.setGravity();
           tv1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.txtview_background,null));
             latout.addView(tv1,params);
            list1=new ListView(getApplicationContext());
            list1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           list1.setId(i+100);
            list1.setAdapter(adapter);
            latout.addView(list1,params);

 }
tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
        list1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case 1:
//list1.setAdapter(adapter);
                list1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 2:
                list1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case 3:
                list1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

and my xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".MainActivity">



</LinearLayout>
```

well, I geting the required list view, only the click of last item... and the image link is below

https://goo.gl/photos/gQfSrjXdHxqd5fTs6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> well, I geting the required list view, only the click of last item... and the image link is below

**Problem**: Only the third `TextView` has the click listener; also the reference to the list is pointing at the third `ListView` after the for-loop.

**Solution**: Set the click listener to every `TextView` in the for-loop, and perhaps keep an array of `ListView`s for the logic on clicks:

```
ListView lists = new ListView[3];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(menu[i]);
        tv.setTag(i);
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_material_dark));
        tv.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.txtview_background,null));
        latout.addView(tv, params);
        lists[i] = new ListView(this);
        lists[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lists[i].setId(i + 100);
        lists[i].setAdapter(adapter);
        latout.addView(lists[i],params);

        // Inside for-loop
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        lists[i].setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Needs some error checking on getId()
    lists[v.getId()].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I need some more help from you, I want to set visibility gone to other view's that are not selected. when I open another view then previous views list view should be closed.

I add some code that is able to set visibility gone and visible to selected view

 if(lists[v.getId()].getVisibility()==View.GONE)
            lists[v.getId()].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            lists[v.getId()].setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Hi, if you have another question the best thing to do it to post it as a new question, so multiple people can help.

Comment: (In your specific case you can use a for-loop in onClick(), with i going from 0 to 2: if i == v.getId() set the list visibility to VISIBLE, otherwise to GONE... but still it is better to ask another question, to keep the website focused and help others through google indexing)

Answer (score 0):

You get the listview only at the bottom because you add it there, you'll have to use:

```
latout.addView(list1, index)
```

where **index** is the position inside the linear layout. 
Moreover if you whant it after the first TextView then index is 1, after the second then is 2 and so on...

That code must be called when the user clicks so you know which TextView and so you'll know index.